# UEFI/BIOS not storing bootloader settings for more than one reboot

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, uefi, x399

I have a PC on which Windows is installed in UEFI mode (not legacy). In order to boot, in the BIOS/UEFI it must be configured so that the system looks for UEFI bootloaders, not legacy ones, on startup. However all settings related to this keep getting reset with every second reboot.
I start the PC, it goes automatically into the UEFI, because it can't find a bootloader. I check the CSM support setting, and it is enabled (CSM allows boot of legacy bootloaders on UEFI systems via emulation) and also "Storage Boot Option Control" is set to Legacy only. One of these settings must be set to "disabled/UEFI only" so that my system can boot. So I change one of them to their correct value. I select save and reboot. My PC turns off, then on for two seconds, then off again (?), then on again and it boots correctly. The next time I restart, I have to do the same procedure again, because these specific settings have been reset to their previous, incorrect value.

The battery is good. All other settings are stored as far as I can tell. I have this mainboard and I updated the BIOS to the latest version: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X399-AORUS-Gaming-7-rev-10#kf
I also made a short video detailing my issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W16uI9UwQ-c

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure fixed it:

- Download the latest BIOS update, reflash it even if you already have it.
- Reboot into the BIOS, load optimized defaults.
- Reconfigure everything.

I guess either I got into some corrupted or fallback state, or I encountered some sort of firmware bug.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know how you fixed your problem